# Not able to import the support file

Tags: android

I cannot import the ActionBarActivity
I tried to compile the support repositaries,in the build gradle but then it shows

Error:(10, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:

The project 'My First App4' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Please help

Comment: could you please post both the gradle files too..

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0' and add compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there is a Project `build.gradle` and a Module `build.gradle`.

This error seems to me as, you have an android block in your Project `build.gradle` file.

**Remove android block from Project `build.gradle`** and the app will compile fine..